# Highcharter dataLabels from different series

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have got the following code: It gives me a linechart with datalabels which correspond to the the values of the `wt` column. However I would like to display the values of the `cyl` series. Something like this: `return(this.series.cyl.y)`

What I actually want to archieve with my "real" dataset is to calculate the difference of the previous value of the same series, which seems to be not possible because `this.point.y` does not return an array, but returns the actual values. So the better solution would be to calculate a new series or column in R and use that column as dataLabel. Can someone help me?

```
library(highchart)

highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(type = "line", data = mtcars$wt, name = "cyl", dataLabels = list(
        enabled = TRUE,
        formatter = JS(
            'function(){
            return this.point.y
            //return(this.series.cyl.y)
        }'
        )
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `format` within `hc_add_series`:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(type = "line", data = mtcars, name = "cyl", hcaes(y = wt), 
                dataLabels = list(
                  enabled = TRUE,
                  format = "{point.cyl}"))
```

Comment: sorry, was on vavation, so I did not see it yet. Helped me a lot. Thank you very much :-)